# Regex to get values between Double Quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I have a value i am pulling from a database

```
 <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8GRDA1gG8R8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I am trying to get the src as a value using regex.

```
Regex.Match(details.Tables["MarketingDetails"].Rows[0]["MarketingVideo"].ToString(), "\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"").Groups[2].Value
```

that is how i am currently writing it

How would I write this to pull the correct value of src?

Comment: Why exaclty are you willing to use `Regex` here? Since is has an XML structure, why not pass it to an `XDocument` instance?

Comment: [Obligitory "don't parse html with regex" link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Really, use an html parser instead.

Comment: Ofcourse, this is HTML, stupid me. Been working with XML much lately! Better to use an HTML parser indeed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this....

```
Match match = Regex.Match( @"<iframe width=""420"" height=""315"" src=""//www.youtube.com/embed/8GRDA1gG8R8"" frameborder=""0"" allowfullscreen></iframe>", @"src=(\""[^\""]*\"")");

Console.WriteLine (match.Groups[1].Value);
```

However, as others have already commented on your question... it's better practice to use an actual html parser.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex to parse xml or html. It's not worth it. I'll let you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), and it sort of exagerates the point, but the main thing to keep in mind is you can get into a lot of trouble with regex and html.

So, instead you should use an *actual* html/xml parser! For starters, use [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx), a class built into the .net framework.

```
string input = "<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/8GRDA1gG8R8\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=''></iframe>";

XElement html = XElement.Parse(input);
string src = html.Attribute("src").Value;
```

This will make `src` have the value `//www.youtube.com/embed/8GRDA1gG8R8`. You can then split that up to get whatever you need from it.

I should also note that your input is not valid **xml**. `allowfullscreen` does not have a value attached, which is why I added `=''`.

If you need to get more complex, such as your input, use an HTML parser (`XElement` is meant for xml). Use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) like this (using the previous example):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(input);

string src = doc.DocumentNode
    .Element("iframe")
    .Attributes["src"]
    .Value;
```

This parser is more forgiving for invalid or incorrect (or just irregular) inputs. This will parse your original input just fine (so missing the `=''`).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn312070(v=vs.85).aspx according to microsoft, the allowfullscreen is true when it exists, and false when it doesn't exist, there is no value to assign.

Comment: @Zack, updated to include the html parser, which will parse the original input correctly.

Comment: var videoCode = details.Tables["MarketingDetails"].Rows[0]["MarketingVideo"].ToString().Replace("\"","'");
            doc.LoadHtml(videoCode);

            video.Attributes["src"] = doc.DocumentNode
                 .Element("iframe")
                 .Attributes["src"]
                 .Value;`

@gunr2171
this code will not work i keep getting an object reference error. IS there something I am missing?

Comment: @CoreyToolis, I don't know, you have not given me enough information to reproduce your issue. Try debugging to see which value is null.

Comment: @gunr2171 the videoCode is not null it gives the iframe value i have listed above. 

doc.DocumentNode
    .Element("iframe")
    .Attributes["src"]
    .Value;
is the null value.